# Is it possible to say "review my skill"

Tags: word-usage, grammar

I want to express that I haven't done programming for years and this project makes me to review my programming skill I learn during my graduation.
Is it correct to say "review my programming skill"?

Comment: A whole sentence is needed. The phrase as written could mean more than one thing.

Comment: You could use '**_revise_**' instead of '_review_'.

Answer (score 1):

'Assess' is a better word. Yes, 'review' might have a relative meaning, but when it comes to one's skills and progress about something, I recommend that you use 'assessment'. (i.e., programming skills assessment)

NOTE: This answer is based on the context that you want to know the extent of your skills. If you add more details to your question, I'd revise as needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. "I want to express that I haven't done programming for years and this project makes me to review my programming skill", i actually want to express I havn't done one thing for years, and this project require me to program, so it re-train my programming skill. Now I am wondering is "refresh my programming skill"  correct?

Comment: Oh! Review or refresh would be okay then.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

> I haven't done programming for years, therefore I want to
>   **review/refresh** my programming skills learnt during my graduation.